# How do you assign a criteria restriction to every alias

Tags: java, hibernate, alias, criteria, restriction

In my example, every child has one parent, and every parent can have multiple children. I am trying to get a list of parents where all of its children are over 18. Below is what I am trying but it's giving me the parents who have at least one child over 18. Any help as to how to adjust my code would be really appreciated.

```
    Criteria cr = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Parent.class);
    cr.createAlias("children", "children");
    cr.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
    cr.add(Restrictions.gt("children.age", 18));
    return cr.list();
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you change the restriction to return all Parents who has no children less than 18? Like this:

```
cr.add(Restrictions.not(Restrictions.lt("children.age", 18)));
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried that but am getting the same results as Restrictions.gt("children.age", 18). The issue is every combination I try gives me the parent if one or more of its children passes the restriction.